# Socket function getting error

Tags: python, sockets

Im trying to do a `socket.gethostbyname` from a list of subdomains concatenated with an argument value but am getting an error. Im not sure if the loop isnt working correctly and the first try is just not a valid subdomain+domain. or if it just isnt working at all?

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./attack2.py", line 40, in <module>
    print subcheck(returned_list, arguments['--domain'])
  File "./attack2.py", line 31, in subcheck
    socket.gethostbyname(sub + domain)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Description:

Basic Domain bruteforcer

Usage:
  attack2.py (-f <file>) (-d <domain>) [-t 10] [-v]
  attack2.py -h | --help

Arguments:
  -f --file File to read potential Sub-domains from. (Required)
  -d --domain Domain to bruteforce. (Required)
Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  -p --proxy    Proxy address and port. [default: http://127.0.0.1:8080] (Optional)
  -t --thread   Thread count. (Optional)
  -v --verbose  Turn debug on. (Optional)
"""
import socket
from docopt import docopt


def fread(dwords):
        flist = open(dwords).readlines()
        return [s.replace('\n', '.') for s in flist]

def subcheck(subdomain, domain):
        for sub in subdomain:
                socket.gethostbyname(sub + domain)
        return output


if __name__ == "__main__":
        arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1a')
        print arguments
        print fread(arguments['--file'])
        returned_list = fread(arguments['--file'])
        print subcheck(returned_list, arguments['--domain'])
```

**NEW def subcheck code**

```
def subcheck(subdomain, domain):
    for sub in subdomain:
            try:
                    #print "%s %d" % (sub+domain,len(sub+domain))
                    print socket.gethostbyname(sub + domain)

            except:
                    print "Some error"
```

**NEW OUTPUT**

```
173.194.34.150
173.194.34.137
Some error
Some error
None
```

Comment: Can we see some example command line input?

Comment: `socket.gethostbyname()` will throw errors if the name can't be resolved; your code needs to be able to handle bad input or hostnames that can't be resolved.

Comment: Add `print repr(sub + domain)` before the call to `gethostbyname` to check what address it is trying to resolve. This will likely shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Example cli:  ./attack2.py -f wordfile.txt -d google.com

Comment: @user4815162342 output from print: ` 'mail.google.com'
'admin.google.com'
'domain.google.com'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./attack2.py", line 41, in <module>
    print subcheck(returned_list, arguments['--domain'])
  File "./attack2.py", line 32, in subcheck
    socket.gethostbyname(sub + domain)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: Does 'ping mail.google.com' return anything for you?

Comment: yeah if i do an interactive python session and do a socket.gethostbyname('mail.google.com') returns an ip address

Comment: The last one on the list, `domain.google.com` does not resolve for me either. If you need to handle such invalid domains, place the call in a `try` block, log the exception, and continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`domain.google.com` and `stuff.google.com` are invalid domains. Getting rid of those will fix the problem.

None is returned because you aren't returning anything in your `subcheck` function. So when you invoke it like this:

```
print subcheck(returned_list, arguments['--domain'])
```

it will be forced to return, and print None. Remove the print in front of it and you won't see None.

Answer (score 0):

"[Errno -2] Name or service not known" sounds to me like your program cannot reach a DNS server. Can you resolve the names in some other way? e.g. using `dig'. I think if socket.gethostbyname cannot resolve the name, it returns a different error; when I try it, I get: "No address associated with hostname".

Comment: yeah if i do an interactive python session and do a socket.gethostbyname('mail.google.com') returns an ip address

Comment: could it be that my code is adding 'mail.google.com' rather than adding mail.google.com ?

Comment: @LearningCode hmm, that might be the problem.

Comment: surely that would come up in the print out?

Comment: I think the 'mail.google.com' is coming from the repr. Could you just do this instead of repr: print "%s %d" % (sub+domain,len(sub+domain)). Also remove the return output from your test function because that will generate an exception as it is undefined.

Comment: done as mentioned above: output is now mail.google.com 15
admin.google.com 16
domain.google.com 17
Some error
stuff.google.com 16
Some error
None
unknown@ubuntu:~$

Comment: ive got it working now. I just need to handle the errors better. new code will appear in orignal question shortly

Comment: So it works for main.google.com, admin.google.com but it fails for domain.google.com/stuff.google.com correct? That would explain it right? Neither of those are valid domains

Comment: Looks that way. Any idea where `None` is coming from in the output?

Comment: Yea. You aren't returning anything in your subcheck function. So when you invoke like this: print subcheck(returned_list, arguments['--domain']) it will be forced to return, and print None. Remove the print in front of it and you won't see None anymore

Comment: still see none after removing print